# Fail to install basemap 1.2.1 with conda due to package conflicts, how to resolve?

Tags: python, package, conda, matplotlib-basemap, proj

I installed Basemap on Conda (Win 10 64, Python 3.7.3) in a non-root environment but I ended up with the problem that [there is no epsg in the proj folder](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/430). Following the advice from github I found out I had version 1.2.0 and tried to install 1.2.1 without success.

EDIT: Apparently it is an incompatibility issue with `proj` as can be seen when trying this:

`conda create -n test python proj basemap=1.2.1 -c defaults -c conda-forge`

First I set channel conda-forge to highest priority and half of my environment got updated due to this, Basemap didn't however.

Then I tried to force an install of 1.2.1 which lead to a detailed report of what packages are in conflict with each other:

```
Package llvm-meta conflicts for:
arrow-cpp -> numpy[version='>=1.16,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
parquet-cpp -> arrow-cpp=0.5 -> numpy[version='>=1.16,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
fastparquet -> numpy[version='>=1.11'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
statsmodels -> numpy=1.11 -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
pandas -> numpy[version='>=1.11.*'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
wordcloud -> numpy -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
mkl-service -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
bokeh -> numpy[version='>=1.7.1'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
blas -> openblas -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
nltk -> numpy -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
liblapack -> libblas==3.8.0=14_openblas -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
matplotlib-base -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
scipy -> blas==1.0=mkl -> libblas==3.8.0=10_mkl -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
libblas -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
scikit-learn -> libcblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> libblas==3.8.0=14_openblas -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
basemap=1.2.1 -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
seaborn -> numpy -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
pyarrow -> numpy=1.11 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
libcblas -> libblas==3.8.0=14_openblas -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
matplotlib -> numpy -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
patsy -> numpy[version='>=1.4.0'] -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
numba -> numpy[version='>=1.11,<1.12.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
numpy -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> llvm-meta[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']

Package clangdev conflicts for:
libblas -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
basemap=1.2.1 -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
scikit-learn -> libcblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> libblas==3.8.0=14_openblas -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
matplotlib-base -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
seaborn -> numpy -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
blas -> openblas -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
libcblas -> libblas==3.8.0=14_openblas -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
bokeh -> numpy[version='>=1.7.1'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
wordcloud -> numpy -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
matplotlib -> numpy -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
fastparquet -> numpy[version='>=1.11'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
numpy -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
numba -> numpy[version='>=1.11,<1.12.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
nltk -> numpy -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
scipy -> blas==1.0=mkl -> libblas==3.8.0=10_mkl -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
mkl-service -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
pyarrow -> numpy=1.11 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
parquet-cpp -> arrow-cpp=0.5 -> numpy[version='>=1.16,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
pandas -> numpy[version='>=1.11.*'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
liblapack -> libblas==3.8.0=14_openblas -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
arrow-cpp -> numpy[version='>=1.16,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
statsmodels -> numpy=1.11 -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
patsy -> numpy[version='>=1.4.0'] -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> libopenblas==0.3.7=h29e5d5d_0 -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0'] -> openmp==5.0.0 -> clangdev[version='5.0.0|5.0.0.*']
```

I'm at a loss what I should do next, neither `llvm-meta` nor `clangdev` are even installed in the environment, so why are there conflicts with non-existing packages?

When installing Basemap 1.2.0 none of those packages are installed either, so unless dependencies changed in version 1.2.1 this makes no sense to me.

I also have no idea which github to report this to, any advice would be helpful.

Here's the output of `conda list`:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12                     py_0    conda-forge
arrow-cpp                 0.15.0           py37h5c295ed_0    conda-forge
asn1crypto                1.2.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
astroid                   2.3.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.8.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
bokeh                     1.3.4                    py37_0    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.70.0               h6a4c333_2    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.7             he025d50_1000    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.15.0            h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.9.11            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.13.1           py37hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003    conda-forge
cloudpickle               1.2.2                      py_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         3
cryptography              2.7              py37hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
cython                    0.29.13          py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
docopt                    0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.15.2                   py37_0    conda-forge
double-conversion         3.1.5                h6538335_1    conda-forge
easyprocess               0.2.7                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                   py37_1000    conda-forge
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                   py_1001    conda-forge
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
fastparquet               0.3.2            py37hc8d92b1_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.0               h563cfd7_1    conda-forge
future                    0.18.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
fuzzywuzzy                0.17.0                     py_0    conda-forge
gflags                    2.2.2             he025d50_1002    conda-forge
glog                      0.4.0                he025d50_1    conda-forge
googletrans               2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpc-cpp                  1.23.0               h4d7d3fa_0    conda-forge
hdfs                      2.5.8                    pypi_0    pypi
ibm_db                    3.0.1            py37hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       64.2                 he025d50_1    conda-forge
idna                      2.8                   py37_1000    conda-forge
imagesize                 1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        0.23                     py37_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipykernel                 5.1.3            py37h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.9.0            py37h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0    conda-forge
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.15.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0    conda-forge
joblib                    0.14.0                     py_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9c                hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.1.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.3.3                    py37_1    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
keyring                   19.2.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37he980bc4_0    conda-forge
langid                    1.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0                    14_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0                    14_mkl    conda-forge
libclang                  9.0.0                h74a9793_1    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0                    14_mkl    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h7602738_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.8.0                h1a1b453_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.17               h2fa13f4_0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.10            h6512ee2_1003    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.30.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.8.3             he025d50_1001    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.1.1                    py37_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.1.1            py37h2852a4a_1    conda-forge
mccabe                    0.6.1                      py_1    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
more-itertools            7.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
networkx                  2.4                        py_0    conda-forge
nltk                      3.4.4                      py_0    conda-forge
numba                     0.46.0           py37hf9181ef_0
numpy                     1.17.3           py37hc71023c_0    conda-forge
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46                       py_0    conda-forge
openpyxl                  3.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1c               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
packaging                 19.2                       py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.25.2           py37he350917_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.7.3                         0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parquet                   1.2                      pypi_0    pypi
parquet-cpp               1.5.1                         2    conda-forge
parso                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pillow                    6.2.1            py37h643dfcc_0    conda-forge
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
ply                       3.11                     pypi_0    pypi
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         2
proj                      6.2.0                ha7a8c7b_1    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.10                     py_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.6.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pure-sasl                 0.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pyarrow                   0.15.0           py37h803c963_1    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_1    conda-forge
pyflakes                  2.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pyhive                    0.6.1                    py37_0
pylint                    2.4.3                    py37_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.12.3           py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.18                  pypi_0    pypi
pyqtwebengine             5.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.15.5           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.3                h510b542_1    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
python-levenshtein        0.12.0          py37hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
python-snappy             0.5.4            py37hd25c944_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0    conda-forge
pyunpack                  0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pywin32                   224             py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.1.2            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37h16f9016_0    conda-forge
qt                        5.12.5               h7ef1ec2_0    conda-forge
qtawesome                 0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
qtconsole                 4.5.5                      py_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
re2                       2019.09.01       vc14h6538335_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
regex                     2019.08.19       py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_1    conda-forge
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.21.3           py37h7208079_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h29ff71c_0
seaborn                   0.9.0                      py_1    conda-forge
setuptools                41.6.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
six                       1.12.0                py37_1000    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.7             h6538335_1002    conda-forge
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 1.9.4                    py37_0    conda-forge
sphinx                    2.2.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0    conda-forge
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_1    conda-forge
spyder-kernels            0.5.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.3.10           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.30.1               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0    conda-forge
tbb                       2019.9               he980bc4_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.2                   py_1001    conda-forge
thrift                    0.11.0          py37h6538335_1001    conda-forge
thrift-cpp                0.12.0            hd042d19_1004    conda-forge
thrift_sasl               0.3.0           py37hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
thriftpy                  0.3.9                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.9             hfa6e2cd_1003    conda-forge
tornado                   6.0.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.36.1                     py_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0    conda-forge
unidecode                 1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
uriparser                 0.9.3                he025d50_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.25.6                   py37_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                   py37_1002    conda-forge
wordcloud                 1.5.0           py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
xlrd                      1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
xlsxwriter                1.2.2                      py_0    conda-forge
xmljson                   0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
xmltodict                 0.12.0                     py_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4             h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
yaml                      0.1.7             hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.2                h6538335_2    conda-forge
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h2fa13f4_1006    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.0                hd8a0e53_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: I'm confused about the difference between the package `proj` and `proj4`. The latter seemed to the standard name in Conda Forge (hosting up to 6.1.11) until two months ago when `proj` showed up on Conda Forge and Anaconda (hosting 6.2.0). So, I guess they're transitioning the package name and you're stuck in the crossfire. `basemap` builds seem to depend on `proj4` which means you can't have `proj` with it and thus can only use PROJ 6.1.11 at latest.

Comment: Good find, I was already wondering why there were no prior versions of `proj` on conda. The weird thing is that `basemap 1.2.0` installs fine with `proj` but doesn't work. I can create a new environment with `basemap 1.2.1` and `proj4` however, so I'll try that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search in different githubs and experimenting I found that there were two separate issues here:

First it was an issue with Spyder/Anaconda/Miniconda, specifically with the automatically created Windows-Shortcut on creating a new Conda environment. Starting Spyder using that shortcut for some reason does not set the PROJ_LIB environment variable while starting Spyder from the console from the active environment gets rid of the error.

Second I found my installed versions were these:

```
basemap                   1.2.0            py37h4e5d7af_0
proj                      6.2.0                ha7a8c7b_1    conda-forge
pyproj                    2.4.0            py37h77f86b8_0    conda-forge
```

And apparently that was a botched install as there was no `espg` file anywhere in the environment.

I created a new testing environment where everything was working and looked at the versions installed there:

```
basemap                   1.2.1            py37h79c95a4_1    conda-forge
proj4                     5.2.0                ha925a31_1
pyproj                    1.9.6            py37h6782396_0
```

After removing the old versions and specifically installing those versions now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try destroying your environment and starting fresh.  Also, it looks like you have almost cloned the base environment, are you sure you need all of those packages?

To remove the environment:

```
conda env remove -n <env name>
```

To create it from scratch, you can specify multiple channels to search within.  The conda-forge channel has the latest releases, but they are not always stable.  The recommendation is to use the default channels when you can.  Try creating the environment using:

```
conda create -n bmap python ipython matplotlib pandas basemap=1.2.1 -c defaults -c conda-forge
```

EDIT

It looks like someone didn't check the dependencies when compiling `proj`.  If you run

```
conda search proj=6.2.0 --info -c conda-forge
```

it shows it a constraint of `- proj4 ==999999999999`.

Comment: Most of that stuff was installed as dependencies of the handful of stuff I actually need. But I guess I'll just try setting up a new environment and see if I can install Basemap 1.2.1 there.

Comment: The problem seems to lie with the `proj`package. Try this to get a similar package conflict: `conda create -n test python proj basemap=1.2.1 -c defaults -c conda-forge`

Comment: Thanks, I'll report this to Proj github then.